# Android - How can i make this intent auto dial

Tags: java, android

How can I make this intent not only goto the telephont dialer with number, but I don't want to hit the CALL button, I just want it to starting dialing when the intent is started.

```
Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:999-999-9999"));
        startActivity(dialIntent);
```

Please advise?
FlinxSYS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Intent.ACTION_CALL` in your intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
```

**EDIT:**
Dont forgot to add `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I tried that and it crashed my app, i have added the code above that im using that works and activates dialpad and posts number.. but does not start dialing w/o pushing send. Thanks!

Comment: I added that code to manifest but it still crashes my app.. thank you in advance. Please advise?

Comment: What code are you using to for that action. Also what error message are you getting in log? Can you paste.

Comment: ok my noob bad.. I added your manifest code at bottom, needed to be added behind other <uses ... like I said , my bad! Than kyou VERY much. =)